# Installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on a laptop as dual boot, can't uninstall it

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uninstall

My laptop is running Windows 10, and I decided it was time to try Ubuntu, so I did. I set up a live USB (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS), and installed it from there, trusting the installer would work. Everything seemingly went fine, until I restarted the system.
Then I got to the GNU Grub bootloader screen (can only type commands), but couldn't load Ubuntu. That's now less relevant since I've since decided to give up on it on my laptop and install it on my pc instead. The uninstall was seemingly simple, just find the partition Ubuntu was in, and delete it. But neither Windows or Ubuntu shows a specific partition where it could be, instead I get this:
https://postimg.cc/1nFDH6Mx
If the image did not load, it doesn't show any other partition other than windows?
The other disk is just one partition(Not Ubuntu), but that's supposed to be like that.
Can someone help me uninstall Ubuntu please? Thanks!

Comment: There's no Ubuntu or any other Linux in the system where you took the screenshot from.

Comment: But I still get the Grub bootloader. Can I get rid of it in some way?

Comment: UEFI settings > Boot menu, change the OS Selection to Windows bootloader manager, as ALWAYS. If you don't know how the UEFI boot works you shouldn't be installing OSes. This isn't an Ubuntu question, next time consider posting at SuperUser.

Comment: Oh right. Guess I never though of changing the boot. That did fix it for me, thanks!

Comment: For completeness: The Ubuntu bootloader (Grub) .efi entry is still there but now you're booting Windows directly so it makes no difference whatsoever. You can remove the entry from Windows but better not to touch the ESP (EFI System Partition) unless you're sure you know what you're doing. Deleting the wrong one may make Windows unbootable.